# Find $f: [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na)$ diverges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

> Find $f: [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$  and $a>0$ such that $f$ is **positive**
> and $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na)$ diverges.

So I thought to build a function which looks like that:
[triangle function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UjRA.png)

But I don't know how to build one, plus it is not positive.
any way I will be glad to see what you thought about.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you question accordingly.

Comment: Just define $f(na) =1$ for all $n$ and $f(x) =0$ if $x\neq na$ for some $n$.

Comment: what kingW3 said, and if "positive" actually means "strictly positive", then use $f(x)=e^{-x}$ if $x \neq na$.

Comment: @kingW3 $0$ is not positive.

Comment: @Tavish : in my country, $0$ is both positive and negative. It's just a convention, everything still works fine. The real problem is people using words instead of symbols. We all agree what $>0$ and $\geqslant 0$ mean, so we should probably all stick to just that and stop using vague and not universally agreed upon concepts like "positive".

Comment: @user3733558 Really? Because I wouldn’t expect something to be called two contrasting things.

Comment: @Tavish like all conventions, there are advantages and inconveniences attached to it, but I assure you, it works fine once you're used to it. But we probably should refrain going further on that tangent in the comments. If you ever happen to lurk in the main chat room, I'll be happy to continue this conversation.

Comment: @user3733558 Alright...I’m just a little surprised.

Comment: thanks guys, i did what kingW3 suggested. 
@user3733558 i meant "strictly positive". sorry for the ambiguity.